# vsftpd does not start

Tags: linux, centos5, ftp

I installed VSFTPD on CentOS but when I try to start the service it fails. What can I do?

Comment: Did you configure /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf?  Did you configure tcp_wrappers (vsftpd uses them!)  Did you add ip_conntrack_ftp and ip_nat_ftp to IPTABLES for connection tracking? Did you add appropriate rules to IPTABLES?

Comment: I opend the port 21 and 20 for vsftpd in iptables

Comment: It fails? Doesn't it show you the reason? Did you check the log files?

Comment: which log file you mean ?

Comment: /var/log/vsftpd.log  is the default log unless you changed it in /etc/vsftpd.conf

Comment: i do not have this file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that i have **another ftp server** run On demand over my server

Answer (score 0):

Check the log files (/var/log). Consult the CentOS manual if you don't know where/how.

Comment: there is no log file over ther i make some change in vsftpd.conf for syslog_enable=yes and so on but there is no result for log file